# SAP DI API how to insert freight cost or get DocEntry value of a newly created sales order?

Tags: sap-business-one-di-api

I can create sales orders with DI API but I cannot update `document.SpecialLines.Freight1` that is read only.

I'm trying to get DocEntry from the document that I just created, so I can then insert lines in RDR3 that is the table containing the freight cost but for that I need the DocEntry value.

How can I get DocEntry while I insert the sales order or after?
How can I insert freight cost ?

Answer (score 0):

You should not not insert records directly into SAP B1 tables.

You can set Qut.SpecialLines.LineType it will change how Freight1 is calculated.